# Python serial port returing null string

Tags: python, pyserial

Reading data from the serial port:
readline() in the below code return the null vector, the reading data from the serial port is hexadecimal number like AABB00EF the putty gives me the output means the communication is working but nothing works via python
here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import serial, time

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = "/dev/ttyUSB0"
ser.baudrate = 115200
#ser.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS 
#ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE 
#ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE
#ser.timeout = None         
ser.timeout = 1              
#ser.xonxoff = False    
#ser.rtscts = False    
#ser.dsrdtr = False       
#ser.writeTimeout = 2    
try: 
    ser.open()
except Exception, e:
    print "error open serial port: " + str(e)
    exit()

if ser.isOpen():

    try:
        #ser.flushInput() 
        #ser.flushOutput()
        #time.sleep(0.5)  
       # numOfLines = 0

       # f=open('signature.txt','w+')

        while True:
          response = ser.readline()
          print len(response)
          #f=ser.write(response)
          print response
         # numOfLines = numOfLines + 1


        f.close()
        ser.close()
    except Exception, e1:
        print "error communicating...: " + str(e1)

else:
    print "cannot open serial port "
```

Answer (score 0):

readline will try to read until the end of the line is reached, if there is no `\r` or `\n` then it will wait forever (if you have a timeout it might work...) instead try something like this

```
ser.setTimeout(1)
result = ser.read(1000) # read 1000 characters or until our timeout occures, whichever comes first
print repr(result)
```

just use this code

```
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0",115200,timeout=1)
print "OK OPENED SERIAL:",ser
time.sleep(1)# if this is arduino ... wait longer time.sleep(5)
ser.write("\r") # send newline
time.sleep(0.1) 
print "READ:",repr(ser.read(8))
```

you can create a readuntil method

```
def read_until(ser,terminator="\n"):
   resp = ""
   while not resp.endswith(terminator):
        tmp = ser.read(1)
        if not tmp: return resp # timeout occured
        resp += tmp
   return resp
```

then just use it like

```
read_until(ser,"\r")
```

Comment: Still getting zero

Comment: what prints? do you even go into the if branch you expect... here copy paste this code exactly  and tell me what is printed

Comment: your above code give me only this                                                                       READ: ''

Comment: then your thing is not just printing out serial commands or you have the wrong baud rate... or it takes too long to spit something out ... is this an arduino by any chance?

Comment: No it's a ARTIX -7 FPGA

Comment: But I am seeing the ouput if access it through the putty.

Comment: without hitting any keyboard keys? you just open the window and there is text that is there? or it comes in after several seconds?  try making the time.sleep longer (like 5) ... if its a dev board alot of those have slow start ftdi uarts

Comment: on putty i hit the key it start displaying the values.

Comment: so you do have to write first... is the key you hit `enter`?

Comment: Ok, let me try this too. then I get back to you thanks

Comment: Now the data start coming as its a 8-byte hexadecimal data but the as CR and LF are not defined it miss few values from each string. Would be a favour if you tell how to define CR and LF

Comment: I dont understand what you mean... CR just means carriage return `\r`, LF means line feed `\n`

Comment: anyway i updated it to use readline again... you need to trigger the data first though by sending the `\r` character

Comment: One quick question can I set the CR and LF in serial port setting like I set port and baud rate

Comment: nope ... newline is always `\n` in `readline` if thats what you mean